# Django: profile & create variables

Tags: django

I have been working with django for awhile now, this isn't a bug however I would like to find out 
why does the create_profile method need to save the profile and created variables?

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

I have tried

```
print >> sys.stderr , "create_user" + str(profile) + (str(created))
```

and they return the User_Profile unicode function return value and a boolean value for created.

My question specifically is the significance of storing the the profile, created values.

```
UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

I have tried calling the statement alone and it works

Comment: What is the line where do you receive the error?

Comment: the error is probably in the print statement if you didn't remove it, since you have no more a variable called profile

Comment: yes I made a mistake the error was in the print statement

Answer (score 2):

It's a common practice to do it if you're going to use them afterwards:

```
profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
if profle.check_something_here:
    return profile.something_else
```

or maybe:

```
profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
if created:
    # do something with the newly created profile
else:
    # do something else if the profile was already there
```

This of course if you need to do something with them. Otherwise `UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)` is correct too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to assign the result of the call to any variables *if you do not need them*. So

```
UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

is fine.

If you are using only one variable and not the other (judging by the error):

```
profile, _ = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```